# R Aligning table content to decimal points in kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I've created a table in RMarkdwon (PDF) with the `knitr` and `kableExtra` packages.
I can choose in the `kable`-function between left,center or right- alignments.
But I want that the content of the table cells are aligned to the decimal points.
In this case it is difficult since there are asterisks behind the numbers indicating the significance.
Here is a reproduceable example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

tribble(
  ~Variable_1,~Variable_2,
  "13.5","4.4**",
  "12.7***","1.2*",
  "0.4","0.3***",
  "2.3**","11.5**"
)%>%
  kable(format = "latex", booktabs=T, escape = T)%>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position")
```

Which produces this table:

[image]

Can someone give me an easy solution directly in R?

If this should not be possible, how would an edit in the latex code look like?

Many thanks in advance!

---

Here is the table provided by bttomio:

[image]

---

One solution could be intersing the variable names in `{}` recommended by https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf page 28.

The code then looks like this:

```
tribble(
  ~Variable_1,~Variable_2,
  "13.5","4.4**",
  "12.7***","1.2*",
  "0.4","0.3***",
  "2.3**","11.5**"
)%>%
  rename_all( ~ str_c("{ ",.," }"))%>%
  kable(format = "latex", booktabs=T, escape = T)%>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position")
```

And the table corresponds to the desired output:

[image]

But the problem is the `full-width`-option in the `kable_styling`-function. If I set this option to `TRUE` the linebreak of large column names disappears.

Comment: Do you have access to the numbers without the stars? If yes, you could leave them in two columns. If not, you could separate the strings from the numbers to create two columns for each variable

Comment: Yes. I have access to the numbers without the stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first try:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - '\usepackage{siunitx}'
  - '\newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=3.2]}'
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

tribble(
  ~Variable_1,~Variable_2,
  "13.5","4.4**",
  "12.7***","1.2*",
  "0.4","0.3***",
  "2.3**","11.5**"
)%>%
  kable(format = "latex", booktabs=T, escape = T, align = "d")%>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position")
```
````

Comment: Yes this code works, but the table does not look really nice. See my updated question.

Comment: A solution to this problem could be adding `%>% rename_all( ~ str_c("{ ",.," }"))` before the `kable`-Function.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: This approach does not work when "striped" is used in the latex_options, but it works when its used in the basic_options. And when a row_spec is added, like printing the text in a row bold, it does not work too.